# Can't click on items on the side menu

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, ionic-framework

I installed the ionic-generator (v0.3.2) for yeoman and scaffolded an application.

I generated the "side menu project" and after having started it in the browser (grunt serve), I can't click any item on the menu.  When inspecting the properties in the browser, I see that the class `disable-user-behavior` has been added to `ion-list`. Although I'm not sure it is related.

I also generated the same project a few weeks ago directly with Ionic (thus, without Yeoman) and I don't have this issue.

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: Ionic's version 1.0.0-beta.5 was the cause. I upgraded Ionic to 1.0.0-beta.5b as advised by mgoku (see https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/issues/52).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Beta 5, you should upgrade to 5b or 6 and it will be resolved.